# PhpStorm shows 0% code coverage, but PhpUnit coverage results are 100%

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, code-coverage

I think I have something wrong with PhpStorm configuration, because when I run PhpUnit configuration with coverage, statistic **shows 0%**, but HTML report from PhpUnit **shows 100%**.

**phpunit.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <php>
        <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_RESULTCACHE" value="true"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit Test Suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./coverage/" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

**Coverage HTML report:** https://prnt.sc/moj2oy

**PhpStorm statistics:** https://prnt.sc/moj3mp

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce that using your phpunit.xml and structure: http://prntscr.com/mol3hf
Any symlinks involved? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11852

Comment: No symlinks, maybe because of Docker? I am running interpreter accroding `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: This is my interpreter configuration https://prnt.sc/mom9f3 and this is docker-compose.yml https://pastebin.com/EhAxYQpa